# Is it possible to set a permanent primary group to a file?

Tags: c#, winapi, acl, group

I have a file that I am trying to change its primary group to `LocalSystemSid` (`S-1-5-32-544`) with the [`SetGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/lb-lu/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setgroup?view=net-7.0#definition) function.
It works fine as long as the program is running.
When I start the program again, the primary group returns to be `S-1-5-21-<domain>-513` (checked with [`GetGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.getgroup?view=net-6.0#definition)):

```
string path = @"c:\tmp\myfile.txt";
FileSecurity accessControl = new FileInfo(path).GetAccessControl();
// S-1-5-32-544
IdentityReference localSystemGroup = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.LocalSystemSid, null);

// S-1-5-21-<domain>-513
IdentityReference group = accessControl.GetGroup(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
// Primary group changed to S-1-5-32-544
accessControl.SetGroup(localSystemGroup);

// Next run it will become S-1-5-21-<domain>-513 again
```

Is it possible to change the primary group to be permanent? So next time I will call `GetGroup` it will return `LocalSystemSid` (`S-1-5-32-544`)?

Comment: You seem to be missing a call to `.SetAccessControl()`. You're only modifying the in-memory representation of the ACL.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks, it works. Submit it as answer and I will mark it as completed